# MySQL JOIN two tables in two places

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.hostname, a.asset_tag, d.model, b.location,
        c.type, a.earmarked, a.earmarked_office, a.earmarked_user,
        a.earmarked_date, a.earmarked_by
        FROM laptops a
        JOIN locations b ON a.location = b.id
        JOIN types c ON a.type = c.id
        JOIN models d ON a.model = d.id
        WHERE b.stock = 1
```

Now, the `a.earmarked_office` field is actually a reference to an ID in the `locations` table, which we're already using to fill in `b.location`. How can I, in the same statement, retrieve the actual location name for `earmarked_office`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join to the table twice:

```
SELECT lt.id, lt.hostname, lt.asset_tag, d.model, l.location,
        c.type, lt.earmarked, lt.earmarked_office, lt.earmarked_user,
        lt.earmarked_date, lt.earmarked_by,
        lteo.??
FROM laptops lt JOIN
     locations l
     ON lt.location = l.id JOIN
     types t
     ON lt.type = t.id JOIN
     models m
     ON lt.model = m.id JOIN
     locations leo
     ON lt.earmarked_office = leo.id
WHERE l.stock = 1;
```

Notes:

- Using table aliases is good.  However, use table aliases to make it easier to follow the logic of the query.
- I don't know what columns you want from the second table.
- Use `as` to rename the columns, so they don't conflict with the columns already coming from `l`.
- You may need a `LEFT JOIN`, if there are unmatched values.

Comment: Thanks - I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the same table several times:

```
SELECT a.id, a.hostname, a.asset_tag, d.model, b.location,
        c.type, a.earmarked, a.earmarked_office, a.earmarked_user,
        a.earmarked_date, a.earmarked_by
        FROM laptops a
        JOIN locations b ON a.location = b.id
        JOIN types c ON a.type = c.id
        JOIN models d ON a.model = d.id
        JOIN locations e ON a.earmarked_office = e.id
        WHERE b.stock = 1
```

Comment: @daninthemix  You must first provide the field you want from`locations`. I gave up giving a random name as I did for `locations.id` in the last `join`